# Variable loop not looping

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

```
package Example;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class solisxdddd {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Lenijs = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
        int solis = 0;
        int skaitlis = 0;
        do {
            System.out.println("Input starting number: ");
            a = Lenijs.nextInt();
            
            System.out.println("Input end number: ");
            b = Lenijs.nextInt();
            
            System.out.println("Input increment: ");
            c = Lenijs.nextInt();
            
            solis = solis + c;
            skaitlis = a + solis;
            
            System.out.println("From A to B is: " + skaitlis );
        } while (skaitlis <= b);
    }
}
```

I am having problems with my loop. I'm making a program where the user inputs a starting number (A) and ending number (B) with an increment of (C). So if the user inputs A=2 B=8 C=2, then the program outputs 2,4,6,8. I can make it output the A and B, but it won't do a loop it would output 2;4;8 instead of 2;4;6;8 even though the while is set to stop at when int skaitlis <= B so it should print until it reaches the number B which is 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to read your input *inside* the cycle. Do not do that.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Input starting number: ");
    int a = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Input end number: ");
    int b = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Input increment: ");
    int c = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("From A to B is: ");
    for (int i = a; i <= b; i += c) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}
```

or

```
while (a <= b) {
    System.out.print(a + " ");
    a += c;
}
```

or

```
do {
    System.out.print(a + " ");
    a += c;
} while (a <= b);
```